# Utility that can search an image for a specific RGB code?

Tags: images, search, color

I'm trying to find a utility that can search an image for a specific RGB code and then highlight the exact pixels with that color code.

I can only find utilities that will tell me the RGB code if I mouse over a pixel, which is not what I need. I need something that can search an image for the RGB code.

Comment: highlighting the pixels will change the color :)   That said, lots of programming languages have functions/classes for manipulating images.  Looping across all pixels in an image looking for a specific color value is relatively trivial in several languages.

Comment: @ivanivan: perhaps it can be done like a selection tool: you can see what is selected but the pixels do not change their color. At least not at 400% zoom level

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

Here's a Python program that takes an image file and two colors, `from_rgb` and `to_rgb`. It creates a new image that's equal to the input except that every pixel colored `from_rgb` is replaced with `to_rgb`.

```
import sys
from PIL import Image

from_rgb = (255, 255, 255)
to_rgb = (255, 0, 0)

with Image.open(sys.argv[1]) as im:
    im.putdata([to_rgb if x == from_rgb else x for x in im.getdata()])
    im.save("out.png")
```

**Option 2**

Use [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/)'s Select by Color tool. Turn off antialiasing, set the threshold to 0, and click on a pixel with the color you want to find.

[image: Select by Color settings]

The marching ants in the below example are the result of clicking on one of the orange pixels.

[image: Example selection]